# Taskbar icons sometimes stay lit. Is there a fix?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, taskbar

Sometimes when I hover my mouse over an icon on the taskbar it will light up as usual. However occasionally the taskbar icon will stay lit, and sometimes show the icons tooltip. It isn't that big of a deal, but it does annoy me.

[image: Taskbar]

The only fix I know of is ending explorer in task manager then restarting it from task manager. I'd like to find a fix that doesn't involve such a disruptive procedure.

Comment: @gronostaj Thank you. Do I delete my question now or what should I do with it?

Comment: You're welcome. You can just leave it there, it will be closed as a duplicate. If anybody stumbles upon it in the future, he will be redirected to that question.